# Sparse eigenvalues using eigen3/sparse

Tags: c++, eigenvalue, eigen3

Is there an distinct and effective way of finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real, symmetrical, very large, let's say 10000x10000, sparse matrix in **Eigen3**? There is an eigenvalue solver for dense matrices but that doesn't make use of the property of the matrix e.g. it's symmetry. Furthermore I don't want to store the matrix in dense.

Or (alternative) is there a better (+better documented) library to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) will do this using [`eigs_sym`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_sym)

Note that computing **all** the eigenvalues is a very expensive operation whatever you do, usually what is done is to find only the k largest, or smallest eigenvalues (which is what this will do).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for and in addition it seems to be a fast library. As this is an answer to my question i will mark it as accepted, but do you have experience using Eigen for that kind of task?

Comment: No personal experience using Eigen for these kinds of things I'm afraid. I tend to use armadillo pretty much exclusively for linear algebra in c++. From a quick glance over the docs it didn't look to me there would be any other way of doing what you wanted without hand coding something using a QR decomposition with sparse matrices.

Answer (score 5):

For Eigen, there's a library named [Spectra](https://spectralib.org/). As is described on its web page, Spectra is a redesign of the ARPACK library using C++ language.

Unlike Armadillo, suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188775/673852), Spectra does support `long double` and any other real floating-point type (e.g. `boost::multiprecision::float128`).

Here's an example of usage (same as the version in documentation, but adapted for experiments with different floating-point types):

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <SymEigsSolver.h>  // Also includes <MatOp/DenseSymMatProd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    using Real=long double;
    using Matrix=Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;

    // We are going to calculate the eigenvalues of M
    const auto A = Matrix::Random(10, 10);
    const Matrix M = A + A.transpose();

    // Construct matrix operation object using the wrapper class DenseGenMatProd
    Spectra::DenseSymMatProd<Real> op(M);

    // Construct eigen solver object, requesting the largest three eigenvalues
    Spectra::SymEigsSolver<Real,
                           Spectra::LARGEST_ALGE,
                           Spectra::DenseSymMatProd<Real>> eigs(&op, 3, 6);

    // Initialize and compute
    eigs.init();
    const auto nconv = eigs.compute();
    std::cout << nconv << " eigenvalues converged.\n";

    // Retrieve results
    if(eigs.info() == Spectra::SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        const auto evalues = eigs.eigenvalues();
        std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<Real>::digits10);
        std::cout << "Eigenvalues found:\n" << evalues << '\n';
    }
}
```