# Eigenvalues of sparse matrix using Eigen3

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3, numerical-analysis

Is there a distinct and effective way of finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real, symmetrical, very large, let's say 10000x10000, sparse matrix in Eigen3? There is an eigenvalue solver for dense matrices but that doesn't make use of the properties of the matrix e.g. it's symmetry. Furthermore I don't want to store the matrix in dense.

Or is there a better (+better documented) library to do that?

Comment: Check out this link for a list of libraries that can find eigenvalues using sparse matrices: [NetLib.org](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html)

Comment: This is a nice list u have there, but I have concerns that this is up-to-date

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188482/sparse-eigenvalues-using-eigen3-sparse

Comment: Just because it was migrated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sparse eigenvalues using eigen3/sparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188482/sparse-eigenvalues-using-eigen3-sparse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a C++ library, check [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).

The [`eigs_sym()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_sym) function seems to be what you want. Quoting the docs, it:

> Obtains a limited number of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of sparse symmetric real matrix X

A minimal example from the docs adapted to your desired matrix size:

```
// generate sparse matrix
sp_mat A = sprandu<sp_mat>(10000, 10000, 0.1);
sp_mat B = A.t()*A;

vec eigval;
mat eigvec;

eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 5);  // find 5 eigenvalues/eigenvectors
```