# Exact condition number of sparse matrix from Eigen

Tags: c++, math, julia, linear-algebra

I have a really large sparse matrix encoded in Eigen in C++ and I need the exact condition number.

Eigen does not have functionality for this.

Someone I know said I should export the matrix and read it with matlab, except I don;t have a matlab license and I would not know how to export it.

I am thinking of using octave or julia instead. All I really need is the condition number somehow with the minimum amount of custom code possible.

Comment: You might want to check your wording.  The wording "condition matrix" does not strike me as a correct description of what you are after.   In any event, eigen *does* provide facilities to compute eigenvalues of a matrix.   And the condition number is the ratio of the magnitudes of the largest-magnitude and smallest-magnitude eigenvalues.    Also your wording using "exact" is not possible - the best you can do is gain a result as accurate as possible within limits of numeric precision.

Comment: I wanted to say condition number, I miss typed.

Comment: @Peter the API for sparse matrices is different than for dense matrices, I cannot find a way to get the singular values of a sparse amtrix.

Comment: Look up the amadillo or spectra libraries.

Comment: Duplicate, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30188482/3740047).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sparse eigenvalues using eigen3/sparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188482/sparse-eigenvalues-using-eigen3-sparse)

Comment: It doesn;t I tried it and spectra takes hours to find the solution. 

I need to do what I described, export the data into a file on disk and load it into a dedicated software for it, matlab is too annoying so octave is probabbly the best candidate, I just don;t know what format to export the data into